# Using knex decrement with async/await

Tags: javascript, postgresql, async-await, knex.js, decrement

I'm getting error with while trying to use knex `.decrement()` withg async/await:

```
  const test = await new CollectionGroup()
    .where('uuid', '=', asset_collection_group_uuid)
    .decrement('item_out_quantity', 1);

  console.log('TEST', test);
```

Output:

```
  sql: 'select "asset_collection_item".* from "asset_collection_item" where "asset_collection_item"."uuid" = ? limit ?' }
err   TypeError: (intermediate value).where(...).decrement is not a function

  - index.js:182 Object.deleteItem
    D:/work/project/src/svc/borrow/item/index.js:182:10
```

I'm not getting error if I remove `.decrement()`:

```
  const test = await new CollectionGroup()
    .where('uuid', '=', asset_collection_group_uuid)
```

What is the correct way to use knex `.decrement()` with async/await?

Comment: What knex version do you have? Did you try to install newest one?

Comment: "knex": "^0.14.3",

Comment: Is that plain knex code or bookshelf or something like that? Anyways it should work the way you wrote it https://runkit.com/embed/4jckqogjywkv You ca try to wrap your object creation to await (new new CollectionGroup()).where(...).decrement(...) though to see if it helps

Comment: `CollectionGroup()` table was imported from bookshelf.

Answer (score 1):

This is how I solved it:

```
  const test = await CollectionGroup.query()
    .where('uuid', asset_collection_group_uuid)
    .decrement('item_out_quantity', 1);

    console.log('TEST', test);
```

Output:

```
{ method: 'counter',
  options: {},
  timeout: false,
  cancelOnTimeout: false,
  bindings: [ '49b7a731-7910-4e9d-9bb2-a27f9f8c210d' ],
  __knexQueryUid: '67ccb2b8-519f-4fea-aab5-c4c287d0d699',
  toNative: [Function: toNative],
  sql: 'update "asset_collection_group" set "item_out_quantity" = "item_out_quantity" - 1 where "uuid" = ?',
  returning: undefined }
TEST 1
```